# Hive: How to get name of cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to get the name of the cluster that hive is running on. Usually, what I do is

```
[user@someVM ~]$ hive -H
*Attached to the someCluster Hadoop cluster*
usage: hive
 -d,--define <key=value>          Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. -d A=B or --define A=B
    --database <databasename>     Specify the database to use
 -e <quoted-query-string>         SQL from command line
 -f <filename>                    SQL from files
 -h <hostname>                    connecting to Hive Server on remote host
 -H,--help                        Print help information
    --hiveconf <property=value>   Use value for given property
    --hivevar <key=value>         Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. --hivevar A=B
 -i <filename>                    Initialization SQL file
 -p <port>                        connecting to Hive Server on port number
 -S,--silent                      Silent mode in interactive shell
 -v,--verbose                     Verbose mode (echo executed SQL to the
                                  console)
```

so here I can easily see `*Attached to the someCluster Hadoop cluster*` and tell which cluster I am on. Next, I tried

```
[user@someVM ~]$ hive -H > out.txt
```

but here is what was captured

```
[user@someVM ~]$ hive -H > out.txt
[user@someVM ~]$ cat out.txt
usage: hive
     -d,--define <key=value>          Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                      commands. e.g. -d A=B or --define A=B
        --database <databasename>     Specify the database to use
     -e <quoted-query-string>         SQL from command line
     -f <filename>                    SQL from files
     -h <hostname>                    connecting to Hive Server on remote host
     -H,--help                        Print help information
        --hiveconf <property=value>   Use value for given property
        --hivevar <key=value>         Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                      commands. e.g. --hivevar A=B
     -i <filename>                    Initialization SQL file
     -p <port>                        connecting to Hive Server on port number
     -S,--silent                      Silent mode in interactive shell
     -v,--verbose                     Verbose mode (echo executed SQL to the
                                      console)
```

note that `*Attached to the someCluster Hadoop cluster*` was not sent to the out.txt file

How can I capture the line `*Attached to the someCluster Hadoop cluster*`?

Comment: `hive` command is deprecated. You should use `beeline`

Comment: thanks, but the systems that I am working on do not have beeline

Comment: Really? It's been part of Hive since at least version 0.13

Comment: i get `bash: beeline: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is how i did it

`hive -H 2>&1 | tee out.txt`

then, `cat out.txt` gives me

```
*Attached to the someCluster Hadoop cluster*
usage: hive
 -d,--define <key=value>          Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. -d A=B or --define A=B
    --database <databasename>     Specify the database to use
 -e <quoted-query-string>         SQL from command line
 -f <filename>                    SQL from files
 -h <hostname>                    connecting to Hive Server on remote host
 -H,--help                        Print help information
    --hiveconf <property=value>   Use value for given property
    --hivevar <key=value>         Variable subsitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. --hivevar A=B
 -i <filename>                    Initialization SQL file
 -p <port>                        connecting to Hive Server on port number
 -S,--silent                      Silent mode in interactive shell
 -v,--verbose                     Verbose mode (echo executed SQL to the
                                  console)
```